# A planned group of especially political, business, or military activities that are intended to achieve a particular aim

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

It's the definition of `campaign` from [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/campaign_1?q=campaign).

It said:

> A planned group of especially political, business, or military activities that are intended to achieve a particular aim

Does it mean `a planned group` or `a planned activities`? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link that you have referenced in your question defines [Campaign](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/campaign_1)—the noun.
So it means *a planned group*.

[Campaign](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/campaign_2)—the verb will define **the act of** *planning activities*

You can also look into the sentence structure (of the noun definition):

> **A planned group of** especially political, business, or military activities that are intended to achieve a particular aim

You can see the subject of the sentence is "the planned group," which is a noun and will define the group.

Answer (score 0):

A planned group of activities, especially in a political, business, or military context.